# Vaciar una pila y crear otra con sus elemntos en orden inverso

Tags: python, lista, pilas, stack

Necesito una función que, dado un objeto de tipo `Stack` devuelva otro objeto de tipo `Stack` con los elementos invertidos y deje vacía la pila original. Solamente puedo utilizar el constructor (que no recibe nada) y los métodos `isEmpty` para determinar si la pila está vacía, `push` para apilar y `pop` para desapilar.

**Nota:** No tengo que implementar un método dentro de la clase `Stack`, sino una función externa a dicha clase.

```
def pila_vacia (self, item):
    self.lista.append(item)
    try : 
        return self.lista.pop()
    except IndexError:
        print ('La pila ya está vacia')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, te dan la propia clase `Stack` (cola LIFO) implementada.

En tu caso usas el método pop para extraer elementos, pero asumes que la clase Stack genera un `IndexError` cuando está vacía, lo cual puede ser cierto o no.

Dado que te dejan usar explícitamente el método `isEmpty`, en principio te bastaría un ciclo `while` que compruebe si la pila tiene aún algún elemento vía mediante dicho método.

El resto es simplemente instanciar una nueva pila (uso indirecto del `__init__`) y usar los métodos `pop` y `push`, el primero sobre la cola recibida y el segundo sobre la creada en cada iteración:

```
def stack_reversed(stack):
    new = Stack()
    while not stack.isEmpty():
        new.push(stack.pop())
    return new
```

Si estamos ante una cola LIFO (último en entrar, primero en salir, o pila), la invertimos sin más al iterar y agregar a la otra cola simultáneamente, por lo que no necesitas ningún contenedor intermedio. Si fuera una cola FIFO, con solo esos métodos, si necesitaríamos un contenedor intermedio para invertirla.

Para probar podemos implementar una cola muy simple (e ineficiente... XD):

```
class EmptyStack(Exception):
    pass

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def push(self,  item):
        self._data.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        if self._data:
            return self._data.pop()
        raise EmptyStack()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return not bool(self._data)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._data)


def stack_reversed(stack):
    new = Stack()
    while not stack.isEmpty():
        new.push(stack.pop())
    return new


stack = Stack()
stack.push(5)
stack.push(6)
stack.push(7)
print(stack)

new = stack_reversed(stack)

print(new)
```

> ```
> [5, 6, 7]
> [7, 6, 5]
> ```

Comment: Al probarla por ejemplo con esta lista :  ```stack_reversed([2,4,3,6,7,45])``` Me devuelve error ```'list' object is not callable``` como tendría que ponerlo

Comment: Hola, según explicas en tu pregunta, se aplica sobre una pila representada por una clase Stack, la función está pensada para funcionar de acuerdo con el enunciado que muestras, recibiendo como parámetro unaa instancia de Stack y retornando otra instancia de Stack, no con listas normales y corriente. Las listas no tienen métodos push ni isEmpty, si tienen método pop. Otra cosa es implementar la clase Stack con una lista interna, mira mi edición. Si la función debe aceptar una lista, entonces el contenido de tu pregunta sería incorrecto.